# ggplot Multiline Title with Different Font Sizes

Tags: r, ggplot2, title, multiline

`<SlightlyLookingAway>`I am attempting to reproduce an excel plot in R.`</SlightlyLookingAway>`  The Excel plot has a two line title.  I know how to handle this by putting a '\n' in the title text.  What I do not know how to handle is that the first line has a larger font size than the second row of the title...  I have done some google searching and have come up with a general lack of response.

I realize that I might be able to cobble something together with an annotation of some kind but that seemed like a kludge. If that is the only answer then it is, but I wanted to ask the community first.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though I have found a hacked solution which gets the job done but does not offer a lot of flexability.  The idea is to put in a math expression using the atop() command along with the bold() and scriptstyle() functions.

```
myplot + 
ggtitle(expression(atop(bold("This is the Top Line"), scriptstyle("This is the second line")))) + 
theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 20))
```

If you know of a better solution with more control over the line spacing and even being able to adjust the font face, please let me know...

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
library(gridExtra)

titleGrob <- function(x=c("First line", "second line"), size=10, ...){
  n <- length(x)
  size <- rep(size, length.out=n)
  one_label <- function(x, size, ...)
    textGrob(x, gp=gpar(fontsize=size), ...)
  lg <- mapply(one_label, x=x, size=size, ..., SIMPLIFY=FALSE)

  wg <- lapply(lg, grobWidth) 
  hg <- lapply(lg, grobHeight) 

  widths <- do.call(unit.c, wg)
  heights <- do.call(unit.c, hg) 

  maxwidth <- max(widths)
  g <- frameGrob(layout = grid.layout(n, 1, width=maxwidth, height=heights) )
  for(ii in seq_along(lg))
    g <- placeGrob(g, lg[[ii]], row=ii)

  g
}

grid.newpage()
g <- titleGrob(size=c(18,12))
grid.arrange(qplot(1,1), top=g)
```

Comment: Ohh, I like this approach... it seems to give a lot more control.  I will have to play with this when I get home.

Answer (score 1):

To perfectly center everything (which `\n` will not do), adapt every size of text whatever the number of lines and at the same time being able to adjust the interlinear space, use this instead:

**e.g.** for smaller to larger text size

```
ggtitle(expression(atop(scriptscriptstyle("whateverline1"),atop(scriptstyle("whateverline2"),atop(scriptscriptstyle(""),textstyle("whateverline3"))))))
```

Then use `labeller=label_parsed`

This also works for `facet_grid`, `xlab` and `ylab`

Note the `scriptscriptstyle("")` to control spacing between lines. You can also use varied relative sizes of text using `scriptstyle` or `scriptscriptstyle` or `textstyle` depending on your needs and of course use `element_text(size=whatevernumber)` in the theme section